# Linux Find and Zip Files

Tags: linux, gzip, find

I'm running into 2 problems when working with my logs and the find command.

1. I am having problems with the mtime option. The 1st command below shows me a few files from March 5th till March 7th, like I believe it should. However, when I add +1 to mtime instead of +0, it only does an ls of the current directory I'm in when running the command. It's just listening my directories under /home/user/. Not sure why +1 is breaking it.

> ```
> sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +0 | xargs ls -l
> ```

2. The second issue I'm running into is I want to find all logs that are older than 1 day and zip them up individually. So if my find command finds 1-1-13.log, 1-2-13.log, and 1-3-13.log, I want each one to be turned into log.gz. I tried this by doing the following command but it isn't working. I assume I may have to do a small bash script for this but was hoping to do it by one quick command.

> sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +0 | xargs gzip -9 *

Most of the examples I've seen involve zipping all files into 1 archive but I want each one individual and I want them to stay in the same location where it found them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What is the output of `ls -l /logs/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I add +1 to mtime instead of +0, it only does an ls of the current directory I'm in when running the command.

Your `xargs` command in this example is weird:

```
sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +0 | xargs ls -l
```

If you want to list the files, just use `find` by itself, e.g:

```
sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +0
```

Or:

```
sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +1
```

If that command produces the list of files you expect, the next step should be easy (below).  If that `find` command *does not* produce the list of files you expect, it suggests that those files have actually been modified more recently than you think.

> The second issue I'm running into is I want to find all logs that are older than 1 day and zip them up individually. So if my find command finds 1-1-13.log, 1-2-13.log, and 1-3-13.log, I want each one to be turned into log.gz.

You have a problem with your xargs command:

```
sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +0 | xargs gzip -9 *
```

You need to get rid of that `*` in your xargs command; you expect the list of files passed to gzip to come from the `find` command, rather than via shell globbing.  So this should work just fine:

```
find /logs -type f -name '*.log' | xargs gzip -9
```

You could also do this using `find ... -exec ...`, but this is typically a less performant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The reason I did the xargs ls command was just to verify my xargs syntax was working correctly. I'm still seeing some weird issues from the +1 but I'll let it go over the weekend to 100% ensure it is older than 1 day. The gzip portion worked fine on my testing and I've redone my crons to try it over the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

2.

```
sudo find /logs/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +0 -exec gzip -9 {} \;
```